# For loop in Formula field. Want Lookup with multiple values

Tags: apex, visualforce, formula-field

Want to populate formula field that gathers all the contacts related to my custom object's record in one formula field with Hyperlinks.

how to accomplish this task ??

```
object :- Conversation__c
Field :- contact__c - Lookup to contact
Field :- totalcontact__c - number
Field :- Contact ids related to this conversation -  Text .. Seperated with |
Field :- Othercontacts__c - formula field. that could populate other contact values with hyperlink to contacts.
```

Comment: So you have one look up to contact from Conversation__c and same time Conversation__c is a parent for many other contacts?

Comment: i have created lookup field on conversation object to contact . want to create more contacts from 1 conversation. Solution :- Juction object can be the solution for this . Case is like 1 conversation have multiple contacts and one contact can have multiple conversation. I am finding alternative of juction object if formula field can read the contact IDS in for loop then it could happen.

Comment: formulas can never refer to collections of objects

Comment: Then you would need a trigger on contact(insert,update,delete,undelete) and update the corresponding Conversation__c. Formula will not work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are describing is a "related list". You can add a related list of Contacts to a page layout, or a visual force page, and if you include the "Name" field as one of the columns in that list, it will also serve as a link to the Contact.

Comment: There Should be atleast links of contact with hyperlink as we have links in related lists.